# XML Parsing Error: not well-formed Location: file:///C:/Users/user/Desktop/Project%202/test.php Line Number 1, Column 3

Tags: php, jquery, xml

I'm trying to get this RSS feed into my page but I get XML Parsing error: now well formed location. I googled this problem but I couldn't find anything related to not well formed location.

Here's my PHP

```
<? $rss = simplexml_load_file('http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/england/rss.xml');

echo '<h1>'. $rss->channel->title . '</h1>';

foreach ($rss->channel->item as $item) {
   echo '<h2><a href="'. $item->link .'">' . $item->title . "</a></h2>";
   echo '<p>' . $item->pubDate . '</p>';
   echo '<p>' . $item->description . '</p>';
}

?>
```

jQuery

```
function rss(){
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'test.php',
    dataType: 'xml',
    success: function (html){
      console.log(html);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Works fine for me. Maybe the feed had an error in it and has since been fixed?

Comment: When I'm using Firefox the console returns the location error. Chrome doesn't seem to able to load the php file.

Comment: If you hit `test.php` directly in your browser, what do you get?

Comment: @AlexHowansky '. $rss->channel->title . ''; foreach ($rss->channel->item as $item) { echo '
' . $item->title . "
"; echo '

' . $item->pubDate . '
'; echo '

' . $item->description . '
'; } ?>